# Keycloak dynamic valid-redirect-uri

Tags: selenium, oauth, keycloak

I have a keycloak client `sample-application`. It has valid-redirect-uri `https://sample-application.mycompany`, a frontend service. This frontend calls backend service, sending JWT token in http header. Backend service checks `allowed-origins` in this JWT token. `https://sample-application.mycompany` is there, so everything works fine in production.

```
"allowed-origins": [
    "https://sample-application.mycompany"
]
```

Now we are doing some e2e tests, and we are calling this backend, but from a different place - `http://jenkins.mycompany`. We have a proper JWT token, but backend service fails on `allowed-origins` validation, because `http://jenkins.mycompany` is not there.

My options:

1. add additional valid-redirect-uri `http://jenkins.mycompany` to my client - I don't want to do that, adding testing stuff to production clients seems bad
2. make copy of a client `sample-application-testing`, with additional valid-redirect-uri, use it for tests, delete afterwards
3. tried using server's private-key to generate my own JWT with extra entry in `allowed-origins`, but it failed later, because server validates this token
4. tried some magic with setting different `Origin` headers, but it seems impossible, browser protection I guess

Is there any other possibility?

Edit - the validation I'm talking about, checks if `Origin` header is in `allowed-origins` list. To be clear: this is not something I invented myself. This validation comes from `keycloak-spring-boot-starter`, here is the relevant fragment: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/17117820cc14f87f5990ddce80ef38a0e2e7f314/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/AuthenticatedActionsHandler.java#L126

Comment: This question is confusing - The backend checks `allowed-origins` in the JWT? I have never heard of a JWT field called this, sounds like you are comparing the "Origin" HTTP header against a list of allowed origins to prevent CSRF attacks? Please be more precise with your wording in this section - if it is checking against the JWT, then say what JWT field it is checking against. If it is comparing against a list, add your test environment into the list. Either way, this question seems to be entirely about testing and nothing to do with OAuth or Keycloak

Comment: Added edit section. `add your test environment into the list` - this is my option number 1 that I mentioned - I don't want to do that, because it interferes with my production client. Unless there is a way to add something to that list, without adding it as valid-redirect-uri in my production client - which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak allows one to add multiple multiple Valid Redirect URIs as well as multiple Web Origins. One of these should allow you to add the URL for your test server and have it appear in the Allowed Origins in the JWT.

More commonly, test environments will have their own copy of production servers so as not to interfere with production operations. This is pretty standard. For a CI/CD setup, it makes more sense to use some kind of a stub or mock validator (something that can be spun up locally) to avoid setting up a server entirely

Below is a screenshot of the settings in the Client configuration in Keycloak 19

[image: Web Origins screenshot]
[image: Valid Redirect URIs screenshot]